# Angularjs directive for definite <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I just started learning angularjs. I find script for change font size but that script change all tags `<p>` on page. How change `<p>` only in `<div class="items-list">`?

```
myApp.directive('textSizeSlider', ['$document', function ($document) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="text-size-slider"><span>Увеличение шрифта</span><input type="range" min="{{ min }}" max="{{ max }}" step="{{ step || 0 }}" ng-model="textSize" class="slider" value="{{ value }}" /></div>',
    scope: {
        min: '@',
        max: '@',
        unit: '@',
        value: '@',
        step: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        scope.textSize = scope.value;

        scope.$watch('textSize', function (size) {
            $document[0].body.style.fontSize = size + scope.unit;
        });
    }
}
```

}]);

```
  <text-size-slider min="12" max="24" unit="px" value="18" step="0">
```

Comment: This is a job for a css style, not for a directive.

Answer (score 0):

In your watch function you can get the element of that class name and in that you can apply changes. Like this

```
 scope.$watch('textSize', function (size) {
      var elementResult = element[0].getElementsByClassName('items-list');
            elementResult.style.fontSize = size + scope.unit;
   });
```

Comment: i have error -- TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontSize' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Although you'd be better off just using CSS for this, here is how to limit it to the active scope:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
  return scope.textSize;
}, function(newTextSize, oldTextSize) {

  var paragraphs = element[0].querySelector('.items-list').getElementsByTagName('p');

  var length = paragraphs.length,
      p, i;

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    p = paragraphs[i];

    p.style.fontSize = size + scope.unit;
  };
});
```